# Android service - populate list view onCreate()

Tags: android, listview, android-service

I've created a service (`BackupBoundService`). In here I've methods to request data to a server using `Retrofit`.

I've a fragment in a tab view that has a list view. This list view has to be populated with the data returned from the request made to the server in the service. I've implemented the code but I'm getting a `NPE` (`NullPointerException`). I know that the binding is an asynchronous event and I strongly believe this is the reason I'm getting the `NPE`.

Here's my service class:

```
private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

/**  
 * Class passed back to the client activity.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public BackupBoundService getService() {
        return BackupBoundService.this;
    }
}


/************************************************
 *                                              *
 *              Service Methods                 *
 *                                              *
 ***********************************************/
```

And here is my `Fragment` class where I bind and call the public methods in the service class:

```
private BackupBoundService backupBoundService;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    (...)

    Utils.isMyServiceRunning(BackupBoundService.class); // Here I get the service is running
    backupBoundService.listAllBackupsInTheCloudAsync(); // Here I get the NPE, saying backupBoundService is null
    return view;
}


// Backup Service
private ServiceConnection backupServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        backupBoundService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;

        Log.d(TAG, "On Service Connected -> Yup!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    Intent intent = new Intent(ApplicationContextProvider.getContext(), BackupBoundService.class);
    ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().bindService(intent, backupServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    Utils.setContext(getActivity());
    Utils.isMyServiceRunning(BackupBoundService.class); // Here I get that service is running
}
```

So, how can I avoid the NPE and still populate the listview on `onCreate()`?

**Check the code comments to understand where the NPE occurs**

Here is my isServiceRunning method, in case someone is wondering:

```
    public static boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        MainActivity myActivity = (MainActivity) getContext();

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) myActivity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.d(TAG, "YES SERVICE IS RUNNING!");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "NO, SERVICE NOT RUNNING");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by calling the method from my service inside `onServiceConnected`

```
// Backup Service
private ServiceConnection backupServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        backupBoundService = binder.getService();
        isBound = true;

        // Call here my method

        Log.d(TAG, "On Service Connected -> Yup!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

It's not the most clean and pretty way to do it IMO but it works. Nevertheless, I'll keep this question open in case someone comes with a better and cleaner solution.